# Linux bash script -

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am trying to use whether or not a line contains a date as a condition for an if statement:

```
if [grep -n -v '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' $line |wc -l==0]
then
...
```

The above returns an error. I don't necessarily need to use grep. The line processed by grep would look like:

```
1984 Dan Marino QB Miami Dolphins
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, what error? How do you expect us to help you if you don't tell us the problem?

Comment: you could be using grep -q to the test.

Comment: When you say *date*, do you mean *year*?

Answer (score 2):

```
if [[ $(echo $line | grep -q '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') ]]; then

# do something
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check this using bash built-ins:

```
re='\b[[:digit:]]{4}\b'
if [[ $line =~ $re ]] ; then 
  echo ok; 
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[grep -n -v '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' $line |wc -l==0]
```

problem 1: `[(space).....(space)]`  you need those spaces

problem 2: there is no `[ foo==bar ]` you can do something like `[ $(echo "0") = "0" ]` or  `[[ $(echo "0") == 0 ]]` here the `$(echo "0")` is an example, you should fill with your commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call grep with `-q` option and check the return value:

```
if [ $(grep -qv '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' $line) -eq 0 ]; then
   # ...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Use command substitution and proper bash syntax.

```
 [[ "`grep -n -v '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' $line | wc -l`" -eq 0 ]]
```